# Spring could not bing properties to 'DataSourceProperties'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I’ve been dealing with a problem for a week, where our whole team can’t find it. Here is the error stack and the configuration we have. Since 1 week and try all the solutions already found on stackoverflow, google, other ... we can not find. Does anyone have an idea? thank you very much

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5f150435 has not been refreshed yet
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5f150435 has not been refreshed yet
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanProvider(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getBindHandlerAdvisors(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getBindHandler(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:107)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Here ours application.properties:

```
# PostgreSQL configuration
#
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://APP0:5432/devdb
spring.datasource.username=devdb
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

# Spring JPA
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.databaseZone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.javaZone=UTC
#Batch
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

used in a microservice with @SpringBootApplication.

We use repository like

```
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<ClientEntity, Integer> {
```

or

```
public interface OrganisationRepository extends JpaRepository<OrganisationEntity, String> {
```

Bellow our pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <akka.version>2.5.22</akka.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    <springfox.version>2.5.0</springfox.version>
    <cassandra-unit.version>3.11.2.0</cassandra-unit.version>
    <opentable.version>0.12.0</opentable.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.5.3</httpclient.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.10.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Actor system -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RxJava 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra-unit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${opentable.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

we have tried multiple solutions, but nothing convincing ...

Anyone have a idea ?

Best regards,
Adrien

Comment: Add `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to your SpringApplication class and try.

Comment: Can you please share the complete stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Can you add the configuration class that defines the `dataSource` bean?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai we don't have the configuration class in our project, the data source is autowired automatically via Spring boot.

Comment: @Amitkumar about EnableAutoConfiguration but we can't use it with SpringBootApplication. We can merge the exclude parameter on SpringBootApplication but now, spring was'nt able to autowire

Comment: @AndyWilkinson is the full stacktrace, the rest has nothing does not make sense for this error and these are normal logs of our application

Comment: sorry if this is not helpful. I am trying to understand what makes the `DataSourceProperties` to be initialised before it is ready. Do you have any scripts data.sql or schema.sql. I am looking at `DataSourceInitializer` class and may be you could put breakpoints to see what triggers it early

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai no scripts, the database is still created and we can't debug directly with breakpoint because the case appears only on un aws environment where a docker is launched ...

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai for initialization it was DataSourceAutoConfiguration before that I make the exclusion about your suggest :-)

Comment: `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` indirectly uses `DataSourceInitializer`. Can you share you pom.xml please? It looks like you have embedded database as dependency  which brings `EmbeddedDatabaseType` in play and triggers the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. `@ConditionalOnClass({ DataSource.class, EmbeddedDatabaseType.class })`

Comment: @AdrienRuffie I don't think that can be the full stacktrace. The two appearances of "Caused by" and "common frames omitted" tells me that there are more exceptions involved. See the stacks of those exceptions should help to show what's triggering really early configuration property binding.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I edit the post for display to you the pom.xml :-) thank againts. If you find a clue

Comment: I assume your `otj-pg-embedded` dependency is for unit tests. But it does not have `test` scope. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai right, I specify the scope <test> and after that I had 
org.postgresql but now the application stop after starting without any clue ... just:  o.a.c.core.StandardService:173|||Stopping service [Tomcat]

Comment: is that because you don't have `org.postgresql` dependency and it was earlier your test lib? http://zetcode.com/springboot/postgresql/

Comment: thank a lot @KavithakaranKanapathippillai that works properly now :-) a great thank to you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

There is dependency that brings embedded `postgresql` which was intended for unit test. Since `test` scope was not specified, it goes into part of `live` app and early initialisation of `datasource` happens which causes the error

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${opentable.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Solution**

- Add test scope to the dependency

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
     <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
     <version>${opentable.version}</version>
     <scope>test<scope> 
  </dependency>
```

- Add the following dependency

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
```